# Unit test multi thread environment with breakpoints in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I am having a problem while debugging a unit test in Visual Studio 2008. The unit test uses a `System.Timers.Timer` (within the business logic) to handle a certain delay (1'000 miliseconds). The thread running the test is put to sleep for 5'000 miliseconds.

When running the test on its own, it passes. When running all tests (>120) it sometimes passes and sometimes fails (**not deterministic**). I then tried setting a breakpoint in the mock object, where I set the flag that is asserted in the unit test. Now when I debug the test on its own, I get the phenomenon, that the `Assert.IsTrue()` fails but the Quick Watch tells me, that it is true:

[image: Assert.IsTrue(true) fails: why?]

```
public class ObjectManagerAccessMock : IObjectManagerAccess
{
    public bool ExecuteCommandWasCalled { get; set; }

    public void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        ExecuteCommandWasCalled = true; //set breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Does the thread running the test continue to run, when another thread is stopped (through the breakpoint)?

Comment: Are you using NUnit tests, or MS tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you're seeing while debugging is a side-effect.  The assertion fails because it is false, but due to threading concerns the value is true by the time you view it in the debugger.

Increasing the timeout in your test should solve the problem, but beware.

Timers seem like a good idea at first but they can lead to problems later on.  Environmental issues, such as other executing processes or running the tests on a slower machine, will drive how the Timers are used.  Unfortunately, if you increment the timeout to the meet the needs of the slowest machine you'll end up with a series of tests that are extremely slow.

Rather than use Thread.Sleep in your test, consider looking at ways to make your tests run as fast as the code does.  For example, raise an event on your test subject when the operation has completed.

```
[Test]
public void DemonstrateThatTheTestRunsAsFastAsTheSubjectUnderTest()
{
     var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

     // configure our test to listen for the completed event
     var subject = new MyTestSubject();
     subject.OnComplete += (sender,e) => resetEvent.Set();

     // perform the long running asynchronous operation
     subject.DoLongRunningOperation();

     // wait up to 10 seconds
     resetEvent.WaitOne(100000);

     Assert.AreTrue(subject.OperationComplete);
}
```

In the above, we use a *ManualResetEvent* which will block execution until the *Set* operation is called.  Also note that I am supplying a timeout value to the reset event so that the operation doesn't run forever.  If the timeout is exceeded it's likely that our *OperationComplete* will still be false, so the test fails.

If you want finer detail to determine if the test timed out, the *WaitOne* method returns a boolean that indicates whether the operation was successful.

```
bool completedWithoutTimeout = resetEvent.WaitOne(10000);
Assert.IsTrue(completedWithoutTimeout, "The operation timed out.");
```

Comment: This sounds like a nice way to go. But I have some problems implementing the `ManualResetEvent`. Does my `subject` need to provide the `OnComplete` method? If so, what should that do? And what is the proper method signature?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. This indeed was part of the solution. Thing was, I had a racing condition in my code, which only occured during unit tests. While testing I don't use an asynchronous queue as in the real code, which resulted in the timer thread being used and competing with the main thread for a certain resource. This caused the test to fail in about 50% of the cases... Classic threading problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sometimes your BL takes up more than 4 seconds so it adds up into more than 5 seconds and assertion fails, but by the time you are able to inspect it with Quick Watch operation is complete and call sets value to true.

Im pretty sure 1) assert fails cause value is false at the time of assertion 2) value is true by the time you check it and time between those 2 actions >0

Comment: it just seems weird, that my BL should suddenly use up to 4 seconds. Running the test on its own with `Thread.sleep(1500);` work just fine. Does VS run more than one test in parallel?

Comment: Im pretty sure MS tests can be doing it in parallel if its configured that way, but you should see more than one test running if it is true.

Comment: You have to enable parallel test execution by manually editing the config file, so doubt parallelism is the issue.

Comment: according to this msdn forum question/answer, unit tests are NOT run in parallel. And I am not aware, that we have changed this behaviour in our environment.